# Secure file uploader by express js and bodyParser

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express, security

I google a lot for finding how to secure file uploading in express js,at end I develop following code to do it.

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.post('/',express.bodyParser({ 
                              keepExtensions: true, 
                              uploadDir: __dirname + '/faxFiles',
                              limit: '20mb'
                            }),function(req,res){
                              checkFile(req.files.faxFile);   
                            });
```

as you see I can limit file size and set uploadDir in bodyParser,now I need to allow user to upload image and pdf only,the way I used is `checkFile` function which contains following code.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var checkFile = function(faxFile){
    if (faxFile.type != "image/jpeg" || faxFile.type != "application/pdf" || faxFile.type != "image/gif"){
        fs.unlink(faxFile.path, function(err){
        });
    } 
}
```

but I think it's not best way,is there any alternative way to do it?such as set file extension in bodyParser constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mmmagic](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic) for strictly checking the extensions. It is an async libmagic binding for node.js for detecting content types by data inspection.

Answer (score 1):

Express uses formidible (https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) for parsing form data, including file uploads.

I don't see an option in formidible to restrict file types, so I'm suggesting Express likely wouldn't have one either.

Answer (score 1):

I created a little gist to show how to check the mime type using mmmagic while streaming the file:

https://gist.github.com/chmanie/8520572

This is more likely to function in a streaming environment like [multiparty](https://github.com/superjoe30/node-multiparty) or [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy).